The Word add-in does not work with hard spaces
I'm a noob in C# and I wanted to improve my work with documents. I made an Add-in with a button that helps me format a given document. I use checkboxes to mark what I want to do with the document and this saves me a lot of time.
One solution doesn't work for me, namely hard spaces. Generally, the program is supposed to insert a hard space in the case of words shorter than 3 characters and located in the slowaKrotkie table. ChatGPT and Copilot corrected my code until it turned out to be such a this monster :) Can you help me why it doesn't work?
 public static void NonBreakingSpace(Word.Document document)
 {
     string tekstDokumentu = document.Content.Text;
     string[] shortWords = { "a", "i", "o", "u", "w", "z", "na", "do", "po", "za", "przy", "nad", "bez", "od", "we", "ze" };
     string[] lines = tekstDokumentu.Split('\n');

     foreach (string line in lines)
     {
         string[] words= line.Split(' ', '\t');

         if (words.Length > 0)
         {
             string lastWord= words[words.Length - 1].Trim();

             if (lastWord.Length <= 2 && Array.Exists(shortWords, oneWord => oneWord.Equals(lastWord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
             {
                 Word.Range range = document.Range(document.Content.End - line.Length + lastWord.Length + 1, document.Content.End - 1);
                 range.Text = "\u00A0";
             }
         }
     }
 }

 private void InsertNonBreakingSpace(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Word.Document currentDocument = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
     NonBreakingSpace(currentDocument);
 }

Help with this code or alternative code that will work

Just to clarify, when you say "hard space" you really mean the Non-Breaking-Space char? i.e. U+00A0?

Can you please edit your code so the names (like ZamienTwardeSpacjeNaKoncuLinijek and slowa) are in English? SO is an English-language site and so it would make your post significantly easier for most visitors here to understand.

Also, what is your function actually meant to do? You say it's meant to "insert a hard-space" somewhere in-relation to short words, but you don't say exactly where the hard-space should go (before the word? after the word? surrounding the word?) or what should happen to the original whitespace chars (preserve? delete? etc?)

Dai, thanks for the answer. Yes, I mean Non Breaking Space char ;)
Of course, I'm already changing the names.
My funcion should change whitespace chars to "hard space (U+00A0) between the word from array and next word.
